# Not able to open configure file in Mule Esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have issue in opening the mule configuring the file..
suddenly my flow file didn't open.
I got this error

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
    org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.munit.coverage.CoverageFigureDecorator.createDecorator(Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/util/MessageFlowEntityWrapper;)Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/figuredecorator/IFigureDecorator;

Also got following error

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.munit.coverage.CoverageFigureDecorator.createDecorator(Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/util/MessageFlowEntityWrapper;)Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/figuredecorator/IFigureDecorator;)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.munit.coverage.CoverageFigureDecorator.createDecorator(Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/util/MessageFlowEntityWrapper;)Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/figuredecorator/IFigureDecorator;
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.figuredecorator.FigureDecoratorFactoryManager.createDecorator(FigureDecoratorFactoryManager.java:74)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.figuredecorator.FigureDecoratorFactoryManager.createDecorator(FigureDecoratorFactoryManager.java:53)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.figure.EntityFigure.updateImageFigure(EntityFigure.java:82)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.figure.ContainerFigure.updateImageFigure(ContainerFigure.java:325)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.figure.ContainerFigure.<init>(ContainerFigure.java:88)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editpart.ContainerEditPart.createFigure(ContainerEditPart.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.getFigure(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:494)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editpart.EntityEditPart.getEntityFigure(EntityEditPart.java:221)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editpart.EntityEditPart.setErrors(EntityEditPart.java:73)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editpart.EntityEditPart.applyErrors(EntityEditPart.java:271)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editpart.MuleConfigurationEditPart.applyErrors(MuleConfigurationEditPart.java:130)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editor.MessageFlowEditor.updateEntityErrors(MessageFlowEditor.java:537)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editor.MultiPageMessageFlowEditor$OnValidateFinishedListener.updateErrorMarkers(MultiPageMessageFlowEditor.java:1675)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editor.MultiPageMessageFlowEditor$OnValidateFinishedListener.access$0(MultiPageMessageFlowEditor.java:1672)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editor.MultiPageMessageFlowEditor$OnValidateFinishedListener$1.call(MultiPageMessageFlowEditor.java:1665)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.editor.MultiPageMessageFlowEditor$OnValidateFinishedListener$1.call(MultiPageMessageFlowEditor.java:1)
    at org.mule.tooling.utils.SilentRunner.run(SilentRunner.java:25)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:17)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner$1.run(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    ... 24 more
```

I also restart anypoint studio many times. I also change my workspace but it didn't work. After installing ObjectConnector this error occured.

I also tried to install fresh anypoint and install connector but still same problem.

Comment: Do you mean the ObjectStore Connector? https://github.com/mulesoft/objectstore-connector

Comment: yes..with dynamix ax connector i got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by updating the munit related updates. [path screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1rfa.png)

**Anypoint studio -> Help -> check Updates ->select the required connectors and munit related updates -> Proceed with the update .**